# matplotlib table values not visible

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is the code I have written for plotting matplotlib table in python.
I get the table but the values are not visible. [Table output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IDxP.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

# plotting the data
fig.patch.set_visible(False)
ax.axis('off')
ax.axis('tight')
ax.table(cellText=[[1,2]], colLabels=["A","B"], loc='center')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.plot()
mc = mpf.make_marketcolors(up='g', down='r')
s = mpf.make_mpf_style(marketcolors=mc)
# axlist[0].legend(legend, prop={'size': 8.5})
mpf.plot(pdata, type='candle', figsize=(
        13, 5), ylabel="Price", title=str(company), returnfig=False, volume=True, style=s) 
#pdata is a dataframe whose candlestick is plotted here.
```

Comment: It works for me.. Do you get any error messages?

Comment: no. just the values are not visible

Comment: The figure you have linked is not created by the code in the question. Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: I only wrote the part of the code responsible for the table. because the code is too long.

Comment: The code also works for me. Whatever your problem is, the snippet you gave us does not reproduce it.

Comment: Check now I have added the code which I have written below the table code. That is for candlestick chart of a dataframe.

Comment: What data do you want to put in the table?

Comment: Try this: add `plt.show()`

Comment: I want to display dataframe in the form of a table

Comment: tried plt.show() already doesnt work

Comment: Try putting `plt.show()` after `plt.plot()`. `mplfinance` will not execute.

Comment: Can you provide the data?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do.  Do you want the candlestick chart and the table on the same Figure?   If so, then the way you are using mplfinance *will not work* because mplfinance is going to create it's own Figure and Axes objects.  You should either (1) first call `mpf.plot()` with `returnfig=True` and then do the table stuff on one of the returned Axes objects, or (2) pass your Axes object into `mpf.plot()` this putting mplfinance [in external axes mode](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/wiki/Acessing-mplfinance-Figure-and-Axes-objects).